# Bold digits in HTML/CSS inline

Tags: html, css, regex

I wonder if it's possible to bold digits only in HTML/CSS? Is it possible to use Regex? I am looking for inline solution. I have a long list of RGB colours listed in a HTML document and would like to only bold digits on that list (so they are visible better). I am looking for more streamlined solutions rather than manually adding tags `<strong>` or `<b>`. In regex I know I can use operator `\d`...

I would like to:

```
r6/g131/b187 r1/g90/b20 r0/g255/b71
```

become this: r**6**/g**131**/b**187** r**1**/g**90**/b**20** r**0**/g**255**/b**71**

Ugly and cluttered code so far:

```
r<b>6</b>/g<b>131</b>/b<b>187</b>
r<b>1</b>/g<b>90</b>/b<b>20</b>
r<b>0</b>/g<b>255</b>/b<b>71</b>
```

Comment: What do you exactly looking for? Do you want to bold using css? Then font-weight is your friend. Do you want to do using HTML? Then strong is your friend. Do you want to do using Regex? Why?

Comment: It's pretty simple: https://regex101.com/r/TFcDlj/1 but you need to specifiy a programming language.

Comment: I have a long list of RGB colours listed and would like to only bold digits on that list (so they are visible better). I am looking for more streamlined solutions rather than manually adding tags <strong> or <b>. In regex I know I can use operator \d...

Answer (score 1):

```js
let str = 'r6/g131/b187 r1/g90/b20 r0/g255/b71';

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = str.replace(/\d+/g, function(match) {
 return '<b>' + match + '</b>';
});
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be to use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to wrap groups of digits in `<strong>` tags.

```js
var content = document.querySelectorAll('td');
content.forEach(function(cell) {
  cell.innerHTML = cell.innerText.replace(/(\d+)/g, '<strong>$1</strong>');
});
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>r6/g131/b187 r1/g90/b20 r0/g255/b71</td>
      <td>r6/g131/b187 r1/g90/b20 r0/g255/b71</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>r6/g131/b187 r1/g90/b20 r0/g255/b71</td>
      <td>r6/g131/b187 r1/g90/b20 r0/g255/b71</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>r6/g131/b187 r1/g90/b20 r0/g255/b71</td>
      <td>r6/g131/b187 r1/g90/b20 r0/g255/b71</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, I am starting with HTML, how do I <span> multiple times? It seems like when I use  first <span>r6/g131/b187</span> - it does the job, then I am using span second time (in the next row) and it's not working. I have a list of colours written in tables <td>.

Comment: You should learn the basics of DOM manipulation with Javascript. Select all `<td>` elements and replace its content like I did with this span.

Comment: I've updated my example to include a table. I hope it helps, @Peter

Answer (score 0):

What you could do if you have a list of RGB colours listed in a HTML document is to look for the pattern and capture the groups and surround them with a `<b>` tag.

```js
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/r(\d+)\/g(\d+)\/b(\d+)/g, "r<b>$1</b>/g<b>$2</b>/b<b>$3</b>")
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <span>r6/g131/b187</span>
    r1/g90/b20
</div>
<p>r0/g255/b71</p>
<span>test = 1</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this

function updateHaystack(input, needle) { return input.replace(new RegExp('(^|\s)(' + needle + ')(\s|$)','ig'), '$1**$2**$3'); } var markup = document.getElementById('somediv').innerHTML; var output = updateHaystack(markup, 'cows'); document.getElementById('somediv').innerHTML = output

Answer (score -1):

It isn't possible with HTML and CSS. You must use Javascript for that, like this.

A simple way to add any style that you want.

```
        var showNumbers = function(tag, className) {
        var text = $('' + tag).html()
        var output = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
            if ($.isNumeric(text[i])) {
                output += "<span class='" + className + "' >" + text[i] + "</span>"
            } else {
                output += text[i]
            }
        }

        $('' + tag).html(output)
    }

    showNumbers('.checkMe', 'numColor')
    showNumbers('.checkMe2', 'numColor2')
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aminqp/yd7ewevg/6/)